# javascript, php, cookies

Tags: php, javascript

the application returns a value "1" in the database instead of the mac address...

I'm able to document.write the output of the mac address, but not able to have it store in the database.

Is the program using the previous cookie? (but Ive deleted all the cookies from the pc)

but if i change the variable mac to string data, it keep refresh my webpage. Why is that so... (var mac="test data";)

Please help!

create_users.php

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function getMacAddress(){
document.macaddressapplet.setSep( "-" );
return (document.macaddressapplet.getMacAddress());
}

function setCookie(c_name,value) {
document.cookie = c_name + "=" +escape(value);
}

//var mac="test data";
var mac = getMacAddress();


setCookie('cookie_name',mac);
window.location = "checkAvailability.php";

</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(getMacAddress());
</script>
```

checkAvailiability.php

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbname = 'registration';
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$javascript_cookie_value = isset($_COOKIE["cookie_name"]) ? $_COOKIE["cookie_name"] : 1;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (mac) VALUES ('$javascript_cookie_value')");
```

Comment: use firebug and look at the Cookie tab to see what was written to cookies.

Comment: but if i used FF, there is no issue with the saving but the browser keep refreshing non-stop...

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
window.location = "checkAvailability.php?mac=" + mac;
```

and eliminate cookie problems?

I presume you've checked that the applet is behaving as you expect?

C.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that code appears in *checkAvailability.php*, then it keeps refreshing because you have `window.location = "checkAvailability.php";` with no logic to stop it running — so every time it loads the page, it gets redirected to that URI.